# how to restrict my application only for iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

in my previous builds . I submitted my application for both iPhones and iPad . but as requirement I have to submitted my app only for iPhones and not for iPads . while for this I changed my my devices from universal to iPhone and  when submitting my binary to App Store it shows error . because from your builds the binary required universal devices like that . for now I want the application only for iPhones

Comment: By default iPhone only app runs in iPad into 1x and 2x size. Your app must be compatible for iPad in 1x and 2x too else your app will be rejected. So keep it universal

Comment: but I need to restrict for iPads from App Store

Comment: My app was rejected with reason so I know iPhone only apps run in iPad but vice-versa not true (You can check instagram for confirmation).

Comment: You cannot make an update more restrictive than the previous version - since your current version is universal (iPad and iPhone) all subsequent versions must be universal too

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the only thing you have to change is the Devices to iPhone on the deployment Info in your Xcode Targets.

In the project part. Check the build settings and change the Targeted Device Family to 1 only.

As for your app being an iPhone only app. You also need to make sure it runs on iPad using the normal 1x and 2x size.

I would then suggest cleaning your build folder and try archiving again. 
(I had to submit another build cause I had the same issue as you had. My app runs only on iPhone. The 1x 2x size is still iphone resolution. You don't have to make a native ipad layout)

Comment: Did you changed your live app from universal to iPhone or you upload it as an iPhone ?

Comment: It is not possible to change from Universal to iPhone only once you have released your app on the store.